# Iterator for a map from a particular position in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

I have a map of elements and a nested loop to iterate over it. But I want the iterator to behave something like this :

```
    map<int,int>::iterator it;
    map<int,int>::iterator it1;
    bool flag=false;

    for(it=m.begin();it!= m.end()-1;it++)
    {
        for(it1 = it+1;it1 != m.end();it1++)
        {
            if((it->first < it1->first)&&(it->second > it1->second))
            {
                flag=true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Basically, the outer loop should start terminate at the last but one postion and the inner loop must start iterating from where the outer-loop iterator is. But this code does not seem to work.(**No Match for + in it+1**) is not defined  Any help would be much appreciated. (Please point out any duplicate links as I could not find one for map.) Thanks !

Comment: `it1 = std::next(it);`

Comment: @PiotrS. Thanks a lot. What if it had to start from 5 positions ahead of the previous iterator ?

Comment: `it1 = std::next(it, 5);`

Comment: then `it1 = std::next(it, 5);`

Comment: @PiotrS. C++11 only ? My compiler doesn't seem to like it..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`std::map<K,V,C,A>::iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is a [*bidirectional iterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator), which means it does not provide `operator+` neither `operator-` (only `operator++` and `operator--` in both prefix and postifx form).

In [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) it is still possible to shift the iterator using [`std::next()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) or [`std::prev()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev) :

```
for (it = m.begin(); it != std::prev(m.end()); ++it)
//                         ~~~~~~~~^ instead of m.end()-1
{
    for (it1 = std::next(it); it1 != m.end(); ++it1)
    //         ~~~~~~~~^ to get the it+1
```

In [c++03](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03) you can use [`std::advance()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) instead to move forward/backward by a given interval (the difference is that it operates on an actual object rather than creates a copy like `std::next`):

```
it1 = it;
for (std::advance(it1, 1); it1 != m.end(); ++it1)
//        ~~~~~~^      ^ number of steps
```

Both methods provide the most optimal way to increment/decrement a given iterator (based on that iterator's traits).

Answer (score 1):

Somthing like this should work too.

```
map<int,int>::iterator it = m.begin();
map<int,int>::iterator end = m.end();
map<int,int>::iterator it1;

bool flag=false;

if ( it != end )
{
   --end;
}

for(it; it != end; it++)
{
   it1 = it;
   for(++it1; it1 != m.end(); it1++)
   {
      if((it->first < it1->first)&&(it->second > it1->second))
      {
         flag=true;
         break;
      }
   }
}
```